# Finding $\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\frac{a_{1}^{1/x}+a_{2}^{1/x}+\cdot\cdot\cdot{a_{n}}^{1/x}}{n}\right)^{nx}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

For non zero positive reals $a_{1},a_{2}\cdot\cdot\cdot a_{n}$ how to find 
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}
   \left(\frac{a_1^{1/x} +a_2^{1/x}+\ldots +a_n^{1/x}}{n}\right)^{nx}?
$$

It becomes indeterminant form $1^{\infty}.$ But difficult to solve by  L'Hospital's Rule. By using A.M.-G.M. inequality it comes that limit is $\geq a_{1}a_{2}\cdot\cdot\cdot a_{n}.$ I also tried by using Squeeze. Please help.Thanks.

Comment: Is it $a_1...a_n $

Comment: take ln of the expression would help.

Comment: @ArchisWelankar That is not really helpful, is it? Answering "How to find the limit" by "here is the limit."

Comment: As you have given the answer so i didnt give it

Comment: You can given another short and nice answer...

Comment: see this answer http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1849862/72031 If the function in current question is $f(x)$ and the function in linked question is $g(x)$ then $f(x) = \{g(1/x)\}^{n}$ and hence $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) = \{\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}g(x)\}^{n}$ and hence the answer for current question is $a_{1}a_{2}\cdots a_{n}$.

Comment: @neelkanth After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/). (Of course, the above only applies if you are satisfied with the answer(s). If not, though, please let me know how I can improve mine.)

Comment: sorry for this ...actually i forgot that...

Comment: No worries -- that happens :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr**

> For $a_1,\dots, a_n$ positive numbers, and $x>0$, $$
> \lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{a_{1}^{\frac{1}{x}}+a_{2}^{\frac{1}{x}}+\cdots+{a_{n}}^{\frac{1}{x}}}{n}\right)^{nx} = \prod_{k=1}^na_{k}
> $$

**Proof.** *Detailed approach, where we use the (low-order) Taylor expansions $e^u=1+u+o(u)$ and $\ln(1+u)=u+o(u)$ when $u\to 0$.*

You can rewrite
$$\begin{align}
\left(\frac{a_{1}^{\frac{1}{x}}+a_{2}^{\frac{1}{x}}+\cdots+{a_{n}}^{\frac{1}{x}}}{n}\right)^{nx}
&= 
\exp\left(nx \ln \frac{a_{1}^{\frac{1}{x}}+a_{2}^{\frac{1}{x}}+\cdots+{a_{n}}^{\frac{1}{x}}}{n}\right)
= \exp\left(nx \ln \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^na_{k}^{\frac{1}{x}}\right)\\
&= 
\exp\left(nx \ln \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n e^{\frac{1}{x}\ln a_{k}}\right)
\end{align}$$
Since $n$ is a constant and $\frac{1}{x}\ln a_{k}\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{} 0$ for each $k$, we have
$$
e^{\frac{1}{x}\ln a_{k}} = 1 + \frac{1}{x}\ln a_{k} + o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)
$$
for each $k$ as $x\to\infty$, and therefore
$$\begin{align}
\left(\frac{a_{1}^{\frac{1}{x}}+a_{2}^{\frac{1}{x}}+\cdots+{a_{n}}^{\frac{1}{x}}}{n}\right)^{nx}
&= 
\exp\left(nx \ln \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n e^{\frac{1}{x}\ln a_{k}}\right)\\
&= 
\exp\left(nx \ln\left( 1+ \frac{1}{nx}\sum_{k=1}^n\ln a_{k}+ o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)\right) \\
&= \exp\left(nx \left( \frac{1}{nx}\sum_{k=1}^n\ln a_{k}+ o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)\right) \\
&= \exp\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\ln a_{k}+ o\left(1\right)\right) \\
&= \exp\left(\ln \prod_{k=1}^na_{k}+ o\left(1\right)\right)
= e^{o(1)}  \prod_{k=1}^na_{k} \\
& \xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{} \prod_{k=1}^na_{k}.
\end{align}$$