# Limit of: $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{1/x}\right)^{nx}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Compute the following limit ($n\in \mathbb{N}$)
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{1/x}\right)^{nx}$$

My idea was to use the inequality:

$$\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} 1^{1/x}\right)^{nx}<\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{1/x}\right)^{nx}<\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} n^{1/x}\right)^{nx} \\
\implies1<L<n^n$$

This gives that the required limit $L$ lies between $1$ and $n^n$. But how can we find its value?

Comment: What about considering $e^{\lim \ln f(x)}$

Comment: @Openspace whoops very correct, will try that out just now. Thanks...

Comment: See related question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1849697/72031

Comment: @Paramanand I think this is almost a duplicate of that. If you think so you can also flag. The answers on that question are also very helpful.

Comment: Consider it done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $e^t=1+t+O\!\left(t^2\right)$, set $t=\frac{\log(k)}x$
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nk^{1/x}\right)^{nx}
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\log(k)}x+O\!\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)\right)^{nx}\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\log(k)}x\right)^{nx}\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+O\!\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)\right)^{nx}\\[3pt]
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\frac{\log(n!)}x\right)^{nx}\cdot1\\[9pt]
&=e^{\log(n!)}\\[15pt]
&=n!
\end{align}
$$

Comment: @GuyFsone perhaps you could be more specific about what the answer doesn't explain on how the answer was obtained.

Comment: @GuyFsone: I have added a couple of steps in case that helps explain what it unclear.

Comment: @GuyFsone why do you insist that must be the answer when the comments below your answer have, multiple times, explained both by example inputting values as well as explaining what you've done wrong?

Comment: @Robjohn thanks, but I cannot understand a basic step, of how log got involved in the second line.

Comment: @samjoe note that $k^{1/x}=e^{(\ln k)/x} $.

Comment: @samjoe: that was explained in the first line. I am using the fact that $e^t=1+t+O\!\left(t^2\right)$ and substituting $t=\frac{\log(k)}x.$ Note that $k^{1/x}=e^t$.

Comment: I hope the downvote is not due to a lack of understanding this answer.

Comment: Oops right, didn't even think of that. Nice answer! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Rob And again how did you split that on line 3?

Comment: @robjohn why was the term in $1/x^2$ dropped ?

Comment: @GuyFsone: it wasn't dropped. That limit was $1$.

Comment: @robjohn then I dont understand that part. it is not clear to me. how you move from first to the second line by pulling out the term $1/x^2$

Comment: @samjoe: $\left(1+\frac ax\right)\left(1+O\!\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)\right)=1+\frac ax+O\!\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)$

Comment: @GuyFsone: see my comment to samjoe above

Answer (score 3):

Let  $$f(h)= \ln\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} k^{h}\right)\implies f'(h) =\frac{\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} k^{h}\ln k \right)}{\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} k^{h} \right)}$$
$$f(0)= 0 ~~~and~~~~f'(0)=\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \ln k\right)=\color{blue}{ \frac{1}{n}\ln \left(n!\right) } $$

Let $x=1/h$ then we have

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{1/x}\right)^{nx} =\lim_{h\to 0}\exp\left(\frac{n}{h}\ln\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} k^{h}\right)\right)\\ =\lim_{h\to 0}\exp\left(n\frac{f(h)}{h}\right)
   =\color{red}{\exp\left(nf'(0)\right) }=\color{red}{n! }  $$

Comment: I don't know why downvotes still exist on your answer, but this answer is also very useful! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @samjoe your are welcome. the owners of the down votes may not be online anymore may that is why