# How to find limit of the given problem?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, exponential-function, factorial, limits-without-lhopital

[image]

How to find this limit ? I've tried this problem but in the middle steps i'm stuck. I'll upload the image of the solution

Comment: I think the $1/x$ is in exponent and not as a factor. If it is a factor then the problem is trivial as first factor tends to $1$ and second factor tends to $\pm\infty$. If $1/x$ is in exponent then just see this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1849862/72031

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

The correct explanation of my Question is this...

Comment: So, mark it as an answer then.

Comment: It takes two days to accept own answer

Answer (score 0):

It's $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\left(1+\frac{1^x+2^x+...+n^x}{n}-1\right)^{\frac{n}{1^x-1+2^x-2+...+n^x-n}\cdot\frac{\frac{2^x-1}{x}+...+\frac{n^x-1}{x}}{n}}=e^{\frac{\ln2+...+\ln n}{n}}=\sqrt[n]{n!}.$$
I used the following.

1.For all $a>0$ we have $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{a^x-1}{x}=\ln{a}.$$

2. Since $\frac{1^x+2^x+...+n^x}{n}-1\rightarrow0$ for $x\rightarrow0$ and $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}=e$, we obtain
   $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\left(1+\frac{1^x+2^x+...+n^x}{n}-1\right)^{\frac{n}{1^x-1+2^x-2+...+n^x-n}}=e$$
3. If there is $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=A,$ where $A>0$ and there is $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow a}g(x)=B$ then there is 
   $$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)^{g(x)}=A^B.$$

Comment: can you please elaborate this solution step by step... ?

Comment: Can i apply L'Hospital's rule ?

Comment: Yes, of course, but it's unnecessary here.

Comment: @Priya Wadhwa I added something. See now.

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1849697/whats-the-proof-for-lim-x-%E2%86%92-0-a-1x-a-2x-a-nx-n1-x-a?noredirect=1&lq=1